# GWT compilation issues / Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, tomcat, gwt, intellij-idea

I have a question regarding GWT compilation. There is a project built on GWT/GXT 2.x which is run under Tomcat on Intellij Idea 14.x. There are a couple of problems I face from time to time and which hard to handle. The first one is that the compilation process doesn't start sometimes and there are no obvious reason for that. For instance, there is a code which is compiled. Then I do slight correctings in the code that can't involved anything. Then I run / debug application under Tomcat-configuration but .nocashe.js- file is not created (`Failed to load resource: com.gxtapp.GXTApp/com.gxtapp.GXTApp.nocache.js the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)` - browser's console output). But even if I revert changes it most likely that I will have the same result.
The second issue is that gwt-module is not compiled when I run it under GWT configuration. As a result I have blank page in browser with gwt-logo in right lower corner. Clicking on this logo makes the module to be compiled.
I tried to add gwt-maven-plugin, but when I compiled project through `gwt:compile` the list of errors was arrised (just for example):

```
    Unable to read: jar:file:/C:/Users/Alex/.m2/repository/com/google/gwt/gwt-user/2.5.1/gwt-user-2.5.1.jar!/com/google/gwt/core/Core.gwtar
Resolving com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.dnd.DND.Feedback
[INFO]       Found type 'com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.dnd.DND.Feedback'
[INFO]          [ERROR] Unable to find class java/lang/Enum
etc.
```

So could you give me a pieces of advice how to adjust Idea / Tomcat / GWT configuration to make compilation process work properly. Thank you in advance.

PS Please find below screenshots with Tomcat and GWT configuration
[image]

[image]